# How to get/create anonymous method from TRttiMethod?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

I want to handle a **`TRttiMethod`** as **anonymous method**. How could I do this?

Here is a simplified example of how I wish things to work:

Interface:

```
TMyClass = class
public
  // this method will be acquired via Rtti
  procedure Foo;

  // this method shall return above Foo as anonymous method
  function GetMethodAsAnonymous: TProc;
end;
```

Implementation:

```
function TMyClass.GetMethodAsAnonymous: TProc;
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  RttiType: TRttiType;
  RttiMethod: TRttiMethod;
begin
  Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    RttiType := Ctx.GetType(Self.ClassType);
    RttiMethod := RttiType.GetMethod('Foo');

    Result := ??????; // <-- I want to put RttiMethod here - but how?
  finally
    Ctx.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want an anonymous method, then make an anonymous method:

```
Result := procedure
          begin
            RttiMethod.Invoke(Self, []);
          end;
```

You can also construct a simple method pointer:

```
var
  Method: procedure of object;

TMethod(Method).Code := RttiMethod.CodeAddress;
TMethod(Method).Data := Self;
Result := Method;
```

The most direct way of course doesn't use RTTI at all:

```
Result := Foo;
```

Comment: Thanks, the first two solutions work for my case. The only caveat in my opinion: they both explicitly repeat the signature of the return type. I hoped for a solution where I wouldn't have to do this. Something that infers that `RttiMethod`'s and `return type`'s signature are compatible.